# Jetpack Compose previews aren't working in Android Studio Flamingo

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

None of my previews are showing anything, but there's no error message.
I'm running on Compose version 1.4.3 and Java 1.8 Kotlin: 1.8.10

The same compose previews were working fine a few days ago on Electric Eel. Is anyone else seeing this?

Tried using a known working branch of my code, but it still doesn't work, so I've concluded it's a problem with Android Studio itself.